# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar una aplicación cliconce del equipo?

Tags: windows, eliminar

Tengo los restos de una aplicación del tipo ClicOnce instalada en mi equipo, que no puedo eliminar ni actualizar. No sé por cuál extraña razón, dio este error (aclaro que la aplicación es de mi autoría), ya que desde hace ya 10 años la vengo usando y actualizando.
Como no se instalaba, busqué en la WEB y encontré que manualmente se podría ir borrando las claves en los diferentes sectores mediante RegEdit, pero me ha quedado una última dirección que no he podido eliminar:
**Equipo\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RADAR\HeapLeakDetection\DiagnosedApplications\Tekno Negocios.exe**

He intentado borrarlo mediante el programa de instalación y desinstalación de Microsoft, pero no aparece en la lista, ni puedo ver la clave del producto.
He llegado a pensar si debería reinstalar el sistema windows (10 pro), pero me parece una locura no poder eliminar los restos de un programa.
Gracias de antemano.

---

No he podido eliminar este programa[image: Tekno negocios]

Comment: aveces cuando se me complica suelo usar esta app `Revo Uninstaller`